# "По-честному-то" — почему ошибка?

Tags: орфография, неологизмы

Ведь правила-то не нарушены! Наречие на *-ому*, частица *-то*.

Comment: Пропущена буква т

Comment: Поправил заголовок)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему ошибка-то? Мне кажется, что никакие правила, действительно, не нарушены.
Вот пример из журнала для учителей словесности, [**"Литература"**](http://ru.calameo.com/read/0018009809d6ddb604ac8) (10/738, ноябрь 2012, стр.6):

*— Но, **по-честному-то**, у нас профессиональное сообщество в печальном виде существует, оно никак не оформлено, мало предметных или межпредметных ассоциаций, которые имели бы экспертный вес.*
Из интервью с Д. Ливановым [с мая 2012 года — министр образования РФ]

**-то**
Словообразовательная единица (постфикс). Отделяется от мотивирующего слова дефисом. Употребляется при **подчёркивании** или смысловом (интонационном) **выделении** слова, к которому относится:

*...есть эксперты независимые, есть эксперты зависимые, и спорьте, судитесь, зарабатывайте на них. Если ребята на вас заработали, почему вам на них не заработать, если все **по-честному-то**?*
Радио "Эхо Москвы". 13.07.2013

Comment: Никогда бы не подумал, что так можно писать, забавно.